# Return multiple values from void and boolean methods

Tags: java, boolean, return

I have the following problem: Having a boolean static method that computes similarity between two integers, I am asked to return 4 results:

1. without changing the return type of the method, it
   should stay boolean.
2. without updating/using the values of external variables and objects

This is what I've done so far (I can't change return value from boolean to something else, such as an int, I must only use boolean):

```
public static boolean isSimilar(int a, int b) {
    int abs=Math.abs(a-b);
    if (abs==0) {
    return true;
    } else if (abs>10) {
    return false;
    } else if (abs<=5){
        //MUST return something else, ie. semi-true
    } else {
        //MUST return something else, ie. semi-false
    }
}
```

Comment: Throw an exception that contains a return value, or mutate an argument, such as an `int[]`, unless it violates constraint 2.

Comment: boolean is either true or false, so you got only these two options there. To return anything else than this two options you need to change the return datatype to something else. End of story

Comment: Who asked you this?  It looks like a trick question to me, where the person doing the asking has a solution that stretches the definitions of the terms they're using in the question.

Comment: It's been on an interview (for an internship) this morning. Believe it or not, the rest of the questions were piece of cake, some IQ, some Java basics. I guess this one made the difference, let's now wait for the results

Comment: Gaaaack.  I was hoping it wasn't an interview question.  I really question the competence of anyone who believes that an interview question like this is going to shed an light on who is more suitable for a position or internship.  Unless they were planning on giving points to the interviewees who said "That would be a really poor way to program".  But maybe someone else can explain to me the value of this sort of question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following is bad practice anyway, but If you can try-catch exceptions you can actually define some extra outputs by convention. For instance:

```
public static boolean isSimilar(int a, int b) {
    int abs = Math.abs(a-b);
    if (abs == 0) {
        return true;
    } else if (abs > 10) {
        return false;
    } else if (abs <= 5){
        int c = a/0; //ArithmeticException: / by zero (your semi-true)
        return true; 
    } else {
        Integer d = null;
        d.intValue(); //NullPointer Exception (your semi-false)
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: From what I heard afterwards, this was one of the accepted answers in the interview

Comment: Oh wow, then i would strongly suggest to leave this company (or to look for another), when such a bad design is considered as an answer in an interview.

Answer (score 1):

A boolean can have two values (true or false). Period. So if you can't change the return type or any variables outside (which would be bad practice anyway), it's not possible to do what you want.

Comment: Except by throwing a RuntimeException, which would work but be a _really_ poor design decision :-)

Answer (score 1):

Does adding a parameter to the function violate rule 2? If not, this might be a possible solution:

```
public static boolean isSimilar(int a, int b, int condition) {
    int abs = Math.abs(a - b);
    switch (condition) {
    case 1:
        if (abs == 0) {
            return true; // true
        }
    case 2:
        if (abs > 10) {
            return true; // false
        }
    case 3:
        if (abs <= 5 && abs != 0) {
            return true; // semi-true
        }
    case 4:
        if (abs > 5 && abs <= 10) {
            return true; // semi-false
        }
    default:
        return false;
    }
}
```

By calling the function 4 times (using condition = 1, 2, 3 and 4), we can check for the 4 results (only one would return true, other 3 would return false).

Comment: It's not clear if it violates the rule, it probably does, it's on the border-line, but I suppose this solution would be acceptable too.